# Startup Scripts on Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

My startup scripts stored in Cloud Storage no longer seem to execute on my Compute Engine instances.

I use the startup-script-url tag to pass in the shell script stored in Cloud Storage. None of my compute engine instances are executing the startup scripts. I'm using Ubuntu images and there is no /var/log/startupscript.log file. I'm providing the proper link to the shell script because if I run:

```
sudo /usr/share/google/run-startup-scripts
```

the instance starts executing the contents of my shell script. These same scripts worked on startup as of last Thursday (9/22) but now they don't. I haven't made any changes to my scripts in that time.

Any idea what is going on? The other questions I found pertaining to this were quite old and did not seem to have an accepted solution.

Comment: It looks like the latest Ubuntu 16.04 was built on 9-22 so I'd imagine my issue relates to that.

Comment: Looks like they reverted to a previous build version. My stuff works again with no changes on my end. Thanks to whomever is looking at this.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments it looks like you've figured this out, but there was a problem in a recent update to Ubuntu 16.04 that broke startup scripts.

The problematic image was rolled-back, but updating packages will cause the problem to occur as well.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages/issues/342